# how to create a database field which is the multiplication of two other fields in drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I have created a table with fields: products and cost, using hook_scheama that takes values from a form.  I want to create a field price which it will be the multiplication of fields: product and cost, and store it in the database.  I also want to display the field in the form.
How can I do that?  I’m not very experienced in drupal

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't be doing that with custom hooks. There is the module [Computer Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field).

Computed Field is a very powerful field module that lets you add a custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the fly during node views.